# Data Conversion Failed SQL

Tags: import, ssis, type-conversion

I am using the import and export wizard and imported a large csv file. I get the following error.

```
Error 0xc02020a1: Data Flow Task 1: Data conversion failed. The data 
conversion for column "firms" returned status value 2 and status text "The 
value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".
(SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
```

Upon importing, I use the advanced tab and make all of the adjustments. As for the field in question, I set it is numeric (8,0). I have since went through this process multiple times and tried 7,8,9,10,and 11 to no avail. I import the csv into excel and look at the respective column, firms. It shows no entry with more than 5 characters. I thought about making it DT_String but will need to manipulate that column eventually by averaging it. Also, have searched for spaces or strange characters and found none.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Not exactly a valid option/answer out of me, but when MS fails me, I go to a third party tool and try it from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Try changing the Numeric precision to numeric(30,20) both in source and destination table.

2) Change the data type to str/wstr and adjust the output column width while importing. It will run fine. It happened with me as well while loading large CSV file of approx 5 GB. After load, use **Try_convert** function to convert it back to numeric and check the values which went null while conversion, you will find the root cause then.

Comment: I ended up following your first suggestion on two other fields and it finally imported. Now on to the next project. Thanks for your assistance.